# Calculating the var(β) in a least square regression model

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-regression, regression-analysis

The linear model that I'm working with is:
$$y_t =α +βx_t + ε_t$$

Based on my Lecture I have:

$$Var(\hatβ) = Var(Σw_tε_t)$$
where $ε_t$ is the error term and
$$w_t = \frac{x_t-\overline x}{Σ(x_t-\overline x)^2}$$

That being said we then have:

$$\begin{align}Var(\hatβ)& = ΣVar(w_tε_t)+ΣΣCov(w_s,ε_t)\\&=E[w_tε_t - E(w_tε_t)]^2\\ &= E[w_tε_t]^2\\&= E[w_t^2ε_t^2]\\&= Σw_t^2Var(ε_t)\\&=σ^2Σw_t^2 \end{align}$$

---

What bothers me the most here is how come:
$$Var(Σw_tε_t) = ΣVar(w_tε_t)+ΣΣCov(w_s,ε_t)$$

and how do we get from this:
$$E[w_t^2ε_t^2]$$ 
to this:
$$Σw_t^2Var(ε_t)$$

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which is exactly the linear model you have? Just one exogenous variable? Are you assuming that the values of $x$ are predetermined (that is, non random) or not?

Comment: Oops, very sorry I just added the linear equation. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: The term $w$ should not have a summation over $x - \bar x$, should it?

Comment: @MarkViola Yes your right I put it there by accident ( just edited my question )

Comment: Check out that there is a $w$ weight for each observation; so I added a $t$ subindex to your definition of those weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not assuming that the $x_t$ values are random, and if you assume no serial correlation and homoskedasticty (that is
$$\text{var}(e_t)=\sigma^2$$
and
$$\text{cov}(e_t,e_s)=0,\quad t\neq s$$
for any $t$ and $s$), then
$$\text{var}(\hat \beta)=\text{var}\left(\sum w_t e_t\right)=\sum w_t^2 \text{var}(e_t)=\sigma^2\sum w_t^2.$$
and you can check that this amounts to
$$\text{var}(\hat\beta)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(x_t-\bar x)^2}.$$

---

The formula with the covariance you give is just wrong. It is true although that
$$\text{var}\left(\sum w_t e_t\right)=\sum \text{var}(w_t e_t)+\sum_{t\neq s} \text{cov}(w_te_t,w_s e_s)=$$
$$=\sum w_t^2\text{var}(e_t)+\sum_{t\neq s} w_t w_s\text{cov}(e_t,e_s),$$
but our assumptions imply that the second term is zero anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That beeing said I don't quite understand how we went from $E[w_t^2ε_t^2]$ to $Σw_t^2Var(ε_t)$ did we use some kind of formula?

Comment: also how come we take out $w$ from the variance. Isn't w a variable?

Comment: If $a$ is not random, then $$\text{var}(aX)=a^2\text{var}(X)$$ and if $\text{cov}(X,Y)=0$ (in particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent), then $$\text{var}(X+Y)=\text{var}(X)+\text{var}(Y).$$

Comment: I'm making the classical assumption that the $x_t$ values are not random but predetermined before measuring $Y_t$ (check if this is the background with which you're supposed to be working). In that case, since the $w_t$ variables only depend on the $x_t$ values, they're not random either and can be thought of as constants (in the probabilistic sense).

Comment: Great, I get it now thank you very much for your help!